Flutter ошибка при компиляции: Error parsing AndroidManifest.xml
Компилирую приложение на Flutter в VS Code, а оно выдает такую ошибку, весь интернет перешерстил, там видел похожие ошибки, но те решения мне не помогли(. Вот ошибка из терминала:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.


com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: Error parsing D:\Setevaya
Apps\student_app\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
39,8s Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Код того самого манифеста:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="setevaya_student"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


Удалите папку android в проекте и выполните flutter create . --platforms=android
